# How to exclude from my populated query each row with the first occurrence of a value which appears in subsequent rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to exclude from my populated query each row with the first occurrence of a value which appears in subsequent rows.

I've looked into offset but this only applies to the whole table

```sql
SELECT
    myTable.name,
    myTable.Id
FROM myTable
GROUP BY myTable.name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY myTable.name ASC, myTable.Id ASC
```

```
What I'm getting:
NAME    ID
A       1
A       2
A       3
B       1
B       2
B       3

What I want:
NAME    ID
A       2
A       3
B       2
B       3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter in the `where` clause:

```
select name, id
from t
where t.id > (select min(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name);
```

Answer (score -1):

I excluded the lowest ID from the query by doing concat and group by finding the MIN value:

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE ( NAME NVARCHAR(MAX), ID INT )

INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES
('A',1),
('A',2),
('A',3),
('B',1),
('B',2),
('B',3)

SELECT * FROM @myTable
WHERE CONCAT(NAME,ID) NOT IN
(
    SELECT CONCAT(NAME,MIN(ID)) FROM @myTable
    GROUP BY NAME
)
GROUP BY NAME,ID
ORDER BY NAME,ID ASC
```

OUTPUT:

```
NAME    ID
A       2
A       3
B       2
B       3
```